# Rotating a sprite with Pyglet without changing its X and Y

Tags: python, pyglet

I have code which rotates a sprite:

```
@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    print('Rotating')

    global player_sprite

    player_sprite.rotation += 1

    if player_sprite.rotation == 360:
        player_sprite.rotation = 0
```

However, this rotates the sprite in a manner I don't want: it changes its x and y position. I want it to remain in the same place -- it's a tank, and is not supposed to move when it turns. If, for instance, I do

```
player_sprite.rotation = 180
```

it not only faces the opposite direction, but is now far away from its original x and y coordinate.

How would I allow the sprite to rotate without changing its x and y?

Here's a link to my [full code](https://pastebin.com/EBD65vsY).

Comment: Is [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/108765) answer useful?

Comment: Perfect! Merci mille fois!